# Is three a way for a Chrome App to reach user's file on hard drive with permission?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome Packaged App with video playback feature.

First of all, I want to allow the user to stream online media (e.g. MP4 video), and at the same time, saving the video to a location chosen by the user. Is there a way to achieve so?

Also, I want to save the locations of media played by the user, and allow the user to play it later without locating it again. Do anyone have some ideas on that?

Thank you guys very much.

Comment: Take a look at mediaGalleries & fileSystem API. They can be used to save the video to a user specified location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want. Your best bet currently is to use the [chrome.fileSytem API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html), which lets you save files to a location chosen by the user. You can also use retainEntry and restoreEntry to allow you to play the files back in later sessions, however I don't believe that is not available in stable channel yet (it is currently restricted to the dev channel, but should be available for general use in version 31).

Also check out the [chrome.mediaGalleries API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries.html). It is designed to provide access to media, however it doesn't provide the write capabilities you need yet.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, the mediaGalleries API is really a good approach for my App. Regarding to the fileSystem API, do you know if there is a way to use it to save an online media stream while playing it at the same time? I think I need a little bit help on that.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming can be done using HTML5 Video tag.

Please check :
http://html5doctor.com/the-video-element/

Also, you can use plugins like :
http://www.videojs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what I'm thinking about is to save the file while streaming. Do you have any ideas on that?